# How BasePage Element Initiating

Tags: java, selenium, oop, selenium-webdriver

How below BasePage parent class initiating elements, when i initiate only Child class elements using- PageFactory.initElements(dr, this);

Below code in Parent Class,

```
@FindBy(how = How.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, using = "Welcome back,")
public WebElement eleUserNameText;

    public BasePage(WebDriver dr) {
        this.dr = dr;
        PageFactory.initElements(dr, this);
    }
```

and below is from child class,

```
@FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "//a[contains(text(),'Sign in with Zappos')]")
public WebElement eleSiginWithZappos;

public HomePage(WebDriver dr) {
    super(dr);
    this.dr = dr;   
}
```

When I use `this` i.e child class, its initiating both eleSiginWithZappos and eleUserNameText(from parent) how its working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question you need to understand a little bit more about how `PageFactory` works.

When you invoke Page Factory like this: `PageFactory.initElements(dr, this);` you pass current instance of an object as the argument.

So you pass `HomePage` instance which extends `BasePage`. These are not separate objects, this is one object.

Page Factory collects all of the fields declared in Child and Parent class. Page Factory use following code:

```
  public static void initElements(FieldDecorator decorator, Object page) {
    Class<?> proxyIn = page.getClass();
    while (proxyIn != Object.class) {
      proxyFields(decorator, page, proxyIn);
      proxyIn = proxyIn.getSuperclass();
    }
  }
```

From the instance of the object you provided, it collects the `Class<?>` which is a schema, not an instance. Then, using `proxyFields()` method, it collects all of the declared fields with `field.getDeclaredFields()`. These fields are fields collected from `HomePage.class` in your example.

The `while` loop, gathers all of the Superclasses of `HomePage` class and initializes their fields.

So the loop in your case looks like this:

```
1. Get schema of HomePage.class
2. Gather declared fields
3. Initialize these fields
4. Get superclass of HomePage.class
5. Gather declared fields
6. Initialize these fields
```

and it does that for all of the classes used in inheritance.

So, if you have 3 classes, A, B, C, all of the fields in these classes will be initialized if they are inherited.

(pseudo - code)

```
class C

class B extends C

class A extends B {
    public A() {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this); //initializes elements in classes A, B and C
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!